# Performance difference between list comprehensions and for loops

Tags: python, optimization, list-comprehension

I have a script that finds the sum of all numbers that can be written as the sum of fifth powers of their digits. (This problem is described in more detail [on the Project Euler web site](https://projecteuler.net/problem=30).)

I have written it two ways, but I do not understand the performance difference.

The first way uses nested list comprehensions:

```
exp = 5

def min_combo(n):
    return ''.join(sorted(list(str(n))))

def fifth_power(n, exp):
    return sum([int(x) ** exp for x in list(n)])

print sum( [fifth_power(j,exp) for j in set([min_combo(i) for i in range(101,1000000) ]) if int(j) > 10 and j == min_combo(fifth_power(j,exp)) ] )
```

and profiles like this:

```
$ python -m cProfile euler30.py
443839   
         3039223 function calls in 2.040 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  1007801    1.086    0.000    1.721    0.000 euler30.py:10(min_combo)
     7908    0.024    0.000    0.026    0.000 euler30.py:14(fifth_power)
        1    0.279    0.279    2.040    2.040 euler30.py:6(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  1007801    0.175    0.000    0.175    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.013    0.013    0.013    0.013 {range}
  1007801    0.461    0.000    0.461    0.000 {sorted}
     7909    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {sum}
```

The second way is the more usual `for` loop:

```
exp = 5
ans= 0

def min_combo(n):
    return ''.join(sorted(list(str(n))))


def fifth_power(n, exp):
    return sum([int(x) ** exp for x in list(n)])


for j in  set([ ''.join(sorted(list(str(i)))) for i in range(100, 1000000) ]):
    if int(j) > 10:

        if j ==  min_combo(fifth_power(j,exp)):
            ans += fifth_power(j,exp)

print 'answer', ans
```

Here is the profiling info again:

```
$ python -m cProfile euler30.py 
answer 443839
         2039325 function calls in 1.709 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     7908    0.024    0.000    0.026    0.000 euler30.py:13(fifth_power)
        1    1.081    1.081    1.709    1.709 euler30.py:6(<module>)
     7902    0.009    0.000    0.015    0.000 euler30.py:9(min_combo)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  1007802    0.147    0.000    0.147    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.013    0.013    0.013    0.013 {range}
  1007802    0.433    0.000    0.433    0.000 {sorted}
     7908    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {sum}
```

Why does the list comprehension implementation call min_combo() 1,000,000 more times than the `for` loop implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because on the second one you implemented again the content of `min_combo` inside the `set` call...

Do the same thing and you'll have the same result.

BTW, change those to avoid big lists being created:

`sum([something for foo in bar])` ->  `sum(something for foo in bar)`

`set([something for foo in bar])` ->  `set(something for foo in bar)`

(without `[...]` they become generator expressions).